# laravel getting undefined varaible when passing to controller?

Tags: laravel

Hope evrything i fine.

I am getting

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

$results = DB::table('Fayrozat')
    ->select('Name', 'Url')
    ->get();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome',compact('results','results'));
});
```

compact(): Undefined variable: results

Any reason ?

Comment: there is no variable named `results` in the scope of that anonymous function ... and there is no controller

Comment: i tried one still  return view('welcome',compact('results'));

Comment: sorry i am passing from web.php

Comment: You must move your DB query block inside your route function. You have declared the $results variable outside of the Route function scope. So the function does not know what $result is.

Comment: I did nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

Need use like this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

$results = DB::table('Fayrozat')
    ->select('Name', 'Url')
    ->get();

Route::get('/', function () use ($results) {
    return view('welcome', compact('results'));
});
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $results = DB::table('Fayrozat')
        ->select('Name', 'Url')
        ->get();

    return view('welcome', compact('results'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just assign your result variable into your route.. & when you passing your variable with your desire name

```
return view('welcome')->with('your_desire',$result);
```

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $results = DB::table('Fayrozat')
        ->select('Name', 'Url')
        ->get();

    return view('welcome', compact('results')); //or return view('welcome')->with('your_desire',$result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no variable named `results` in the scope of that anonymous function. You need to tell the function to use a variable from the parent scope, which PHP has the syntax for with the `use` keyword:

```
function (...) use (...) {
}
```

Though you don't want to be running that query in a routes file like that, so this probably shouldn't be happening in the first place. Just do this query in the route handler:

```
Route::get(..., function (...) {
    return view(..., ['results' => DB::...]);
});
```

Comment: should I create a controller

Comment: @user123456 probably not a bad idea .. not sure why you are doing this query in the routes file though

Comment: it is single page app for testing

Comment: just throw that into the handler